# Bootstrap data-toggle attribute not reverting back to old tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/lakshkhamesra/pen/poEGzzj) or view below the code.

If you click on a tab, its content will show successfully, then click on another tab, that content will also show successfully, however after that, if you go back to the previous tab that you just clicked, then that previous tab's content won't show, instead, the second tab's content will simply remain there. Why is this the case?

JS:

```
$k('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  //new tab
  console.log(e.target);
  
  //previous tab
  console.log(e.relatedTarget);
})
```

CSS:

```
/*nice Menu*/
.rotate {
    -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
.rotate.down {
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pad-15 {
    padding: 15px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both; 
}
.clear:after, .clear:before{ 
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
a.toggle-nav {
    top: 12px;
    right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 22px;
    background: #DE5939;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.nice-nav {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    float:left;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.nice-nav li.child-menu span.toggle-right {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 3px;
}
.nice-nav ul li a {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    position: relative;
}
.nice-nav ul li.child-menu ul {
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
}
.nice-nav ul li.child-menu ul li a {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.nice-nav > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nice-nav > ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2px auto;
}
.nice-nav ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade.show{
    display: none;
}
/*nice Menu*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `nav` in your `ul` class.

From your code from this:

```
<!--nice menu-->
   <div class="nice-nav">
       <ul>
```

To this:

```
<!--nice menu-->
   <div class="nice-nav">
       <ul class="nav d-block" aria-orientation="vertical">
```